# Hypergeometric test of overlapping regions of ChIP-seq datasets

Tags: overlap

I have three different bed files of genomic peak regions from ChIP-seq experiments. I am using R library `phyper` to do the hypergeometric test. To do so, I need the values of sample size, overlapping regions in the samples, population size and the expected number of overlapping regions from the population.

One way to get the population size (number of peak regions in whole genome) is the genome size divided by median length of the peak regions. However, I am not sure what would be the number of overlapping regions in entire population (genome).

In other words, for `phyper` input, I need four values:

```
phyper(q, m, n, k, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
where, n = x - m
```

1. q= Number of success events in sample. In my case it is overlapping peak region of 3 bed files.
2. m= Number of success in population. In this case, it is the value of possible overlapping peak regions if we take entire genome. I do not have this value.
3. x= Number of peak regions in the entire population. In my case, it is the possible number of peak regions in the entire genome. Also I do not have this value.
4. k= Sample size. In my case it is the total number of peak regions in 3 bed files without repeat.

Now, my question is how can I generate the values for `x` and `m` to do the hypergeometric test. Or, is what would be the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

[image: The figure below says about the sample size and overlapping peak regions]

Comment: In the figure it would be `k` instead of `n` for "number of peak regions in 3 bed files". My apology for the typo.

Comment: You should update the picture in your question, to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Figure updated. Thanks!